# how to use same routes in two different route groups

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware

Please i have two route::group, the first is for normal staff and the second is for hod and normal staff.

```
//staff
Route::group(['middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\lecturerMiddleware','as'=>'staff::'], function() {
    Route::match(['post','get'],'application', ['as'=>'application','LeavessController@index'])->name('application');
});

//HOD and Provost

Route::group(['middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\hodProvostMiddleware'], function() {
    Route::match(['post','get'],'application', 'LeavessController@index')->name('application');
    Route::match(['post','get'],'applied', 'LeavesController@applied');
    Route::match(['post','get'],'approval/{id}', 'LeavesController@approval');
});
```

If i access application route as Hod its working but when i try to access as a normal staff its nt working

//HodProvostMiddleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    $user = $request->user();
    if ($user && ($user->user_access_id == '3' or $user->user_access_id == '2')) {
        return $next($request);
    }else return new Response(view('unauthorized')->with('role', 'HOD'));
}
```

// staffMiddleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if ($request->user() && $request->user()->user_access_id == '1') {
        return $next($request);
    }else return new Response(view('unauthorized')->with('role', 'LECTURER'));
}
```

}

Comment: Update your question with your App\Http\Middleware\hodProvostMiddleware code. I suppose your checks there are not correct.

Comment: @katsarov have done that sir